# Can I insert ListEntry to WorksheetEntry using Google Spreadsheet API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

According to [here] (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), we can add rows (ListEntry) to ListFeed using Google Spreadsheet API. I am wondering if we can also add rows to a worksheet (WorksheetEntry) and then insert the WorksheetEntry to WorksheetFeed. It seems that doing so will avoid talking to the GoogleDocs server as many times as the number of rows is. But I have searched a lot without any luck!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a batch request, as described here:
[What is the fastest way to update a google spreadsheet with a lot of data through the spreadsheet api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug)

Good Example:

CellDemo.java 
http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r93/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

it has a processBatchRequest function.