# Google Spreadsheet Java API: URL from CellEntry?

Tags: java, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I am using Java to read from a Google Spreadsheet. The user may select certain cells, and later may update those cells, but in between may shut the program down.

So I would like to store a unique URL for a spreadsheet cell to disk, for later use in updating that spreadsheet cell, when the program restarts. Is there any way to get a unique URL from a CellEntry?

The only way I know of doing this is by getting the cell's row & columns:

```
int row = cell.getCell().getRow();
int col = cell.getCell().getCol();
```

And then using that in a query for cells with min/max rows/cols:

```
URL cellFeedUrl = new URI(worksheetFeed.getCellFeedUrl().toString()
+ "?min-row="
+ Integer.toString(row)
+ "&max-row="
+ Integer.toString(row)
    + "&max-col="
    + Integer.toString(col))
+ "&min-col="
+ Integer.toString(col)).toURL();
CellFeed cellFeed = spreadsheetService.getFeed(cellFeedUrl, CellFeed.class);
```

But this seems a little crazy, since by the time I have a cell entry, I shouldn't have to search for it again. Wishful thinking?

Comment: I only 1/2 understand, is the issue speed?

Answer (score 2):

Fast batch update solution: [What is the fastest way to update a google spreadsheet with a lot of data through the spreadsheet api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug/14616584#14616584)

Also look at **CellDemo.java** http://gdata-java-client.googlecode.com/svn-history/r51/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

it shows you can do an update this way:

```
CellEntry newEntry = new CellEntry(row, col, formulaOrValue);
service.insert(cellFeedUrl, newEntry);
```