# Google Spreadsheet Python API read specific column

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I have 2 questions regarding google spreadsheet's api using python. My google spreadsheet is as follows:

a    b
1 2
3 4 
5 6

When I run the script below I only get

```
root@darkbox:~/google_py# python test.py
1
2
3
4
```

I only want to get column 1  so i want to  see 

1

3

5

my second issue here is considering there is a space between the rows my script is not getting the second part (it should be 5 in this case)

How can I get the specified column and ignore white spaces?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gdata.docs
import gdata.docs.service
import gdata.spreadsheet.service
import re, os

email = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
password = 'passw0rd'
spreadsheet_key = '14cT5KKKWzup1jK0vc-TyZt6BBwSIyazZz0sA_x0M1Bg' # key param
worksheet_id = 'od6' # default
#doc_name = 'python_test'
def main():
    client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
    client.debug = False
    client.email = email
    client.password = password
    client.source = 'test client'
    client.ProgrammaticLogin()

    q = gdata.spreadsheet.service.DocumentQuery()
    feed = client.GetSpreadsheetsFeed(query=q)
    feed = client.GetWorksheetsFeed(spreadsheet_key)
    rows = client.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_key,worksheet_id).entry

    for row in rows:
       for key in row.custom:
         print "%s" % (row.custom[key].text)
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: With CellFeed, the cell data you get back includes a cell id that includes row/col info.

Answer (score 0):

**To ignore white spaces:**
Suggest you switch to CellFeed - I think list feed stops reading when it hits whitespace. Sorry, I forget the fine details. But I dropped List feed and switched to cellfeed a long time ago.

Comment: Problem with this is it takes a very long time (many api calls) to update many cells using a CellFeed.

Comment: @MS_SL Fast update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug/9495293#9495293 did a test, took 5 seconds to insert 4000 cells into a 40,000 cell sheet