# Use CellFeed to clear a cell containing numeric value

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I am trying to to use [CellFeed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data#work_with_cell-based_feeds) to clear some cells in a google spreadsheet. I'm using a batch update to improve speed, so I can't use `CellEntry.update()`.
I create cells and feed them to a batch.

If I set the cell with `new CellEntry(row, col, "")`, cells that contained text are cleared, but numeric values remain.

I also tried `new CellEntry(Cell.createFullCell(row, col, "", null, "")` to clear the number and calculated value as well, but that didn't help.

Any hints on how to clear the number as well?

I sure hope for a SpreadsheetService to replace this stupid and slow API...

Comment: How to do batch update:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402733/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-update-a-google-spreadsheet-with-a-lot-of-data-throug 
KRR is right  changeInputValueLocal() is what I use, works for me.

Comment: Regards speed - the size of a single sheet has the most impact. Smaller sheets are faster, a lot faster, does not matter how many sheets you have. But if you want a lot of control ethercalc is opensource google style spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing contents of a cell with numeric value you should use:

CellEntry.changeInputValueLocal() method.

Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#changing_contents_of_a_cell_1) for more details.

Comment: That doesn't help, the numerical value stays. `CellEntry.changeInputValueLocal()` calls `Cell.withNewInputValue()` which creates a new Cell same as `Cell.createFullCell()`does

Comment: It was a ridiculous programming error; the column counter was incremented twice, so the targeted cell was skipped...